# Meteor cordova build - how to deploy to device?

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I have been reading https://meteor.hackpad.com/Getting-Started-With-Cordova-Z5n6zkVB1xq#:h=Device-Setup and the docs on how to deploy a cordova app are a bit lacking, as to be expected with very new functionality! I execute: `meteor build <bundle path> -p <host>:<port>` which has built my app, I have a tarball for the server and an /android folder which contains an `AndroidManifest.xml` and all sorts of other files - I assume I need to compile this into an APK.

Is this correct? Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside "bundle path"/android you will find you apks already compiled.